# Progress bar is not reaching inside ImageLoadingListener methods while loading the image on Android ViewPager

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, progress-bar

In my Android project, I am using a view pager to move the images. The images are coming and loading from server. So while loading i want to show a progress bar. To do the same i have used ImageLoadingListener inside instantiateItem() method of View Pager. But what i have observed that progress bar is not going inside the onLoadingStarted() or onLoadingComplete() method.

Here is my code for instantiateItem():

```
    @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
            false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
    if(thumb_url.get(position) != null)
    {
      imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url.get(position), imageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Testing", "Load started**********************");
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                FailReason failReason) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Testing", "Load completed");
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout, 0);
    }
    return viewLayout;
}
```

Also here is the method which is getting called to during the image loading:

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView, ImageLoadingListener imgListener)
{
    Log.d("Testing", "getting the image  "+url);
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
    {
        Log.d("Testing", "bitmap is present on the cache ");
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    else
    {
        Log.d("Testing", "bitmap is not present on the cache ");
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(defalt_icon);
    }
}
```

I am not able to fix it. Can anyone help please.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: Can anyone please help.

Comment: can you show your layout_fullscreen_image.xml layout file.